# Show selected Row and Column in CellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cells, tablecellrenderer

I have a `JTable` and everytime I select a cell, I want to print its row and column index. I use `getSelectedRow()` and `getSelectedColumn()` methods for that reason. Running the code below:

#### Class TestTimeTable

```
public class TestTimeTable extends JFrame{
    private final int rows = 10;
    private final int cols = 8;
    private final String daysOfTheWeek[] = {"MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY"};
    private final JPanel jTablePanel;
    private final JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private final JTable timeTable;
    private final Object[][] rowData;

    public TestTimeTable(){
        this.rowData = new Object[this.rows][this.cols];
        this.timeTable = new JTable(this.rowData,this.daysOfTheWeek){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        this.timeTable.setRowHeight(200, 200);
        this.timeTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        this.timeTable.setOpaque(true);
        this.timeTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        this.timeTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        this.timeTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        this.timeTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new BoardTableCellRenderer());
        this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.timeTable, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        this.jTablePanel = new JPanel();
        this.jTablePanel.add(this.scrollPane);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(this.timeTable), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public int getColumn(){
        return this.timeTable.getSelectedColumn();
    }

    public int getRow(){
        return this.timeTable.getSelectedRow();
    }

    public JTable getTimeTable(){
        return this.timeTable;
    }

    public void createAndShowUI(){
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] argas){
        TestTimeTable tt = new TestTimeTable();
        tt.createAndShowGUI();
    }
}
```

#### Class BoardTableCellRenderer

```
class BoardTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    Component c;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Color selectionBlue = new Color(131,166,198);
    private final MatteBorder border = new MatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (table.isCellSelected(row, column)){
            c.setBackground(this.selectionBlue);
            setBorder(this.border);
        } else {
            c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        if(isSelected){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, table.getSelectedRow() + ""+table.getSelectedColumn(),null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Everytime I select a cell, the `JOptionPane` frame appears and then the app freezes. So I have to interrupt it all the time. Could somebody please tell me why is this happening? What could I do to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

- use, override `boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus` (built_in methods) from `getTableCellRendererComponent` instead of referencing back to JTable - `table.isCellSelected(row, column)`, ba reseting Color for rest of cells in else statement, e.g. simple torso

.

```
   private class StatusRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (isSelected) {
                setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
```

- change [ListSelectionMode for JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)
- remove every this.Xxx, are useless
- don't to setSize, use JFrame.pack() instead and/or set size for JScrollPane  e.g. `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());`(for reasonable numbers or rows and columns, otherwise use Dimension(x, x))

EDIT

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.UIResource;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TableRolloverDemo {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRolloverDemo");
    private JTable table = new JTable();
    private String[] columnNames = new String[]{"Column"};
    private Object[][] data = new Object[][]{{false}, {false}, {true}, {true},
        {false}, {false}, {true}, {true}, {false}, {false}, {true}, {true}};

    public TableRolloverDemo() {
        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            //private boolean ImInLoop = false;

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return Boolean.class;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 0) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 0) {
                    //if (!ImInLoop) {
                    //    ImInLoop = true;
                        Boolean bol = (Boolean) aValue;
                        super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
                        for (int i = 0; i < this.getRowCount(); i++) {
                            if (i != rowIndex) {
                                super.setValueAt(!bol, i, columnIndex);
                            }
                        }
                    //    ImInLoop = false;
                    //}
                } else {
                    super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
                }
            }
        };
        RolloverMouseAdapter rolloverAdapter = new RolloverMouseAdapter(table);
        RolloverBooleanRenderer renderer = new RolloverBooleanRenderer(rolloverAdapter);
        table.addMouseListener(rolloverAdapter);
        table.addMouseMotionListener(rolloverAdapter);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, renderer);
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class RolloverMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        private int row = -1;
        private int column = -1;
        private JTable table;

        public RolloverMouseAdapter(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
        }

        public boolean isRolloverCell(int row, int column) {
            return this.row == row && this.column == column;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            int lastRow = row;
            int lastColumn = column;
            row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            column = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            if (row == lastRow && column == lastColumn) {
                return;
            }
            if (row >= 0 && column >= 0) {
                table.repaint(table.getCellRect(row, column, false));
            }
            if (lastRow >= 0 && lastColumn >= 0) {
                table.repaint(table.getCellRect(lastRow, lastColumn, false));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            if (row >= 0 && column >= 0) {
                table.repaint(table.getCellRect(row, column, false));
            }
            row = column = -1;
        }
    }

    private class RolloverBooleanRenderer extends JCheckBox implements
            TableCellRenderer, UIResource {

        private final Border noFocusBorder = new EmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
        private RolloverMouseAdapter adapter;

        public RolloverBooleanRenderer(RolloverMouseAdapter adapter) {
            super();
            this.adapter = adapter;
            setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            setBorderPainted(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {

            getModel().setRollover(adapter.isRolloverCell(row, column));
            if (isSelected) {
                setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                super.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
                setBackground(table.getBackground());
            }
            setSelected((value != null && ((Boolean) value).booleanValue()));
            if (hasFocus) {
                setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("Table.focusCellHighlightBorder"));
            } else {
                setBorder(noFocusBorder);
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TableRolloverDemo tableRolloverDemo = new TableRolloverDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also I cannot use `return this` because class cannot be converted to Component

Comment: you would need that in the case, if you want to subclass (e.g. JLabel from public Component getTableCell...) or override for concrete methods (JLabel.setIcon), otherwise isn't required (e.g. for change color, font or Border) for simple rendering job, you'll see that my edit here

Comment: thank you! It's very close to what I want! It selects non-contiguous cells too! I believe this is also possible without using checkboxes..

Answer (score 1):

> I have a JTable and everytime I select a cell, I want to print its row and column index.

I would override the `changeSelection(...)` method of the JTable:

```
JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
{

    public void xxxchangeSelection(
        int row, int column, boolean toggle, boolean extend)
    {
        super.changeSelection(row, column, toggle, extend);

        System.out.println(row + " : " + column);
    }
};
```